# Force user to select an option from slicer before displaying data in excel

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, slicers

I have a table which is is populated from summarized data. Because of this, when no options are selected from either slicer my data is invalid as it is averaging averages. Is there a way through VBA code or some sort of advanced options where I can make sure the user has selected a choice from both slicers before seeing the data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the user hasn't selected anything, the FilterCleared property should be true.
You could set defaults when true using something like this.

```
With MyWorkbook.SlicerCaches("MySlicer")
    If .FilterCleared Then
        .TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange Format(Date - 7, "m/d/yyyy"), Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")
    End If
End With
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this? I'm very new to VBA and have set up macros with VBA code. Is this something I just paste into a module for the workbook?